# Building a "re"- streaming video server with vlc as core

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming

I am creating a re-streaming video server based on VLC (streaming, transcoding,etc). The main goal of this software component is to abstract users from the video source (webcam, screen,ip-cameras,files,etc) avoiding to view the video without previous auth. The problem is that the same video can be requested with different properties by distinct users. The questions are.

1. How can i do this with VLC?
2. How can i stream to multiples location with VLC?
3. Is VLC a good choices for that work?

Answer (score 1):

You need a software called media server to effectively handle this task. VLC or ffmpeg or other software like that is good to process input streams and transcode them. Media servers may take the processed stream and handle end-users connections.

Please specify what protocol you'd like to use for users' playback to see what's the best choice for your case.

Comment: What i am building is something like a media server then. I am using C# for this work. There exists some basic project to start (C#)